# Syntax error when using cron job to deploy firebase project

Tags: node.js, firebase, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to deploy my project every 10 minutes using cron job in a ubuntu server.

I have a shell script that contains python script after it finished the firebase command will be executed.

this is the shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7
cd /home/User/app.firebaseapp.com
/usr/local/bin/python3.7  Main.py
/usr/local/bin/firebase deploy --token "token"
```

the shell is executed perfectly if I run it using:

```
sh file.sh
```

However, when I add the shell script to cron job an error will show up

error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js:26
var { configstore } = require("../configstore");
    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

Here is the cronjob:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/10 * * * *  /home/User/app.firebaseapp.com/file.sh >> /tmp/a.log 2>&1
```

Thank you

Comment: Hey Rayed, have you tried it without the unexpected token? `var configstore = require("../configstore");`

Comment: Hello Janneck, I can't use it without the token because I'm running the code on the server. However, when I run the shell script, the project will deploy successfully . I guess that means the token is good. Thank you Janneck.

Comment: Which Nodejs version do you have?

Comment: the version is  v12.16.1